# How to add selection criteria dyanmically in Java or SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to implement a functionality where I have to query a database with input parameter values. Input values are optional.

For example

I have a table student with following fields

a)student_id
b)student_roll_no
c)student_first_name
d)student_last_name .. etc

I am need to write a dao layer function so as to retrieve student details depending upon input criteria or parameters.

1) if Input contains only student_id then query should be
select * from student where student_id = :inputStudentId

2) if Input contains  student_id, firstName then query should be
select * from student where student_id = :inputStudentId and first_name = :inputFirstName

like wise for other input parameters, please note input parameters can be 0 to n size

Please suggest what is the best approach to do it? 
I dont wann add null checks and append the query for not null parameters. I want to try something reasonable and logical either in Java or sql (named query)

I am using java1.6 and hibernate

Comment: Are you asking how to build a `String`? If so, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). --- For best quality answer, you should show *how* your DAO method gets the input criteria, and what you've tried so far, i.e. show the code you have.

Comment: Andreas I am not asking how to build a string, I will get those value in DAO funtion for example hentStudentInfo(studentId, firstName, lastName ......)

Comment: But your entire question seems to be around how to build the SQL statement (a `String`), depending on your input. --- Also, don't show code in a comment, edit the question. --- What are the types of the parameters? How do you detect if a value was given or not? --- Don't answer. Edit question and clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Hibernate, you can use HSQL to do that in following manner:

```
query=em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.id=:id");
query.setParameter("id",studentIt)
```

For exact API details, check the documentation @ http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

You can also use `CriteraApi` - this is made for dynamic query creation.

Comment: thanks for reply but as I mentioned i might get studentId as null, would above code work? wouldn't it compare student id with null when input studentId is null?

Comment: If you can have null PKs than something is not right ... Anyway, you can always try `WHERE s.id=:id OR id IS NULL`. But no, null values will not work in this case, where clause must be modified - use CriteriaAPI for such conditional queries building.

Comment: I will have data in database perfectly fine. my question was I might get studentID as null in input paramter for example hentStudentInfo(int studentID, firstname..) . hence my input paramters may or may not be null. if input parameter is null then query would form as SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.id=null I want that if a parameter is null then that parameter should not be used so query will be SELECT s FROM Student s; or is there a way i can handle it SQL ?

Comment: And my question is should the query or should not return any results if id=null. Idk your data model. Anyway you got the solution - either conditional WHERE s.id=:id  or IS NULL, or use criteria API, or concatenate string yourself

Comment: :) I should get the result if parameter is null :) I dont wann handle it via concatenating strings, it looks ugly. i am looking for a better approach neither i wann handle it by adding conditional WHERE s.id=:id or IS NULL. I am tired of looking for an better approach but couldnt find any :(

Comment: @RohitKolhekar Parameter `int studentID` *cannot* be null. Java primitive datatypes cannot be null, so your comment is ... confusing.

Comment: Andreas I was giving an example, mistakenly i put it as int please consider it as an Integer

Comment: @RohitKolhekar then read about CriteriaAPI. It will allow you to do `if(sId==null) conditions.add(builder.isNull("id")) else conditions.add(builder.eq(id,sId));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by dynamically building your HQL with optional Parameters something like shown below:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters= new HashMap<String,Object>();
parameters.put("firstName", firstName);
parameters.put("lastName", lastName);


StringBuilder hql = "SELECT student FROM Student as student where 1 = 1";
if (firstName != null) {
  hql.append(" and student.firstName in :firstName");
}
if (lastName != null) {
  hql.append(" and student.lastName in :lastName ");
}


Query query = session.createQuery(hql.toString());


for (String p : query.getNamedParameters()) {
  query.setParameter(p, parameters.get(p));
}
```